# VBA Update links from Master File to Multiple Files

Tags: excel, vba

I have a master file that stores a lot of information. I have around 50 to 60 files that have vlookup formulas that are referencing the master file. These are also being printed out using a Print vba. When I print off the documents with the print vba the formulas are not updating based on the information in the master file.

Below is the code I have in the Master file.

```
Sub Calc()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Application.Calculation = xlManual
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
        ws.Calculate
    Next ws
    Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
End Sub
```

Comment: Please specify your question. The code, You posted manually calculates each worksheet and then sets excel to automatic calculation. It is unclear how the code goes with the text.

Comment: I am new to vba coding and found this on the internet when searching for help.  I need the formuals in the separate files to update when the master file is updated.

Answer (score 1):

`Application.CalculateFullRebuild`should be sufficient, as described in the [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/office/vba/api/excel.application.calculatefullrebuild?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Dde-DE%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm133272);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue).

If you would like to update (some) worksheets individually, use something like this:

```
Sub updateAllOpenWorkbooks()
    
''
'' For all open workbooks, forces a full calculation of the data and rebuilds the dependencies.
''
'    Application.CalculateFullRebuild
    
' otherwise loop over all workbooks and worksheets
'
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    
    
    For Each wb In Application.Workbooks
        ' update links
        wb.UpdateLinks
        
        For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
            ' calculate manually
            ws.Calculate
        Next
    Next
    
End Sub
```